# Table View out of the window screen iOS objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

I have set constraint for my text field in story board. I want to create a table view under the text field with the following code. Setting the width similar to the `textfield.frame.size.width` brings the tableView all the way out of the screen, why? Please help.

```
-(void)cofigureAutoComTableView
{

    autocompleteTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.txtActivity.frame.origin.x,self.txtActivity.frame.origin.y+32,self.txtActivity.frame.size.width, 200) style:UITableViewStylePlain];

    autocompleteTableView.delegate = self;
    autocompleteTableView.dataSource = self;
    autocompleteTableView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    //autocompleteTableView.
    autocompleteTableView.hidden = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:autocompleteTableView];

    CALayer *layer = autocompleteTableView.layer;
    [layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [layer setCornerRadius: 4.0];
    [layer setBorderWidth:1.0];
    [layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
}
```

[image: Pics]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks ike that because you are calling function when textview is that long, use it in `viewDidAppear`

```
[self cofigureAutoComTableView];
```

Comment: Why is it like that? Don't quite understand. After i called it at viewDidAppear instead of viewDidLoad. it works.

Comment: @HansheungCheah In `viewDidAppear` all layouts has been set. It will also work in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

Comment: Because the view is completely loaded when viewDidAppear is called. When you place the same code in viewDidLoad, it picks up frames from the storyboard, which you have already realised, are way too bigger than screen size.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
 -(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    if(once)
    {
        once = NO;

        [self conf];

   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in viewDidLoad the frames are not in the final form. Only in viewDidAppear the frames are final.

The best solution in this case is to update the autocompleteTableView's frame in viewDidLayoutSubviews.

viewDidLayoutSubviews is called every time the viewController's view frame is updated.

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    autocompleteTableView.frame = CGRectMake(self.txtActivity.frame.origin.x,self.txtActivity.frame.origin.y+32,self.txtActivity.frame.size.width, 200);

}
```